# Get public IP address of client using TcpListener C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I have written a small TCP server using System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener and the code is not relevant so [Microsoft's Example TcpListener code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netcore-3.1) can be used instead.

I want to get the public IP of the client but I am unsure how to, I have read a couple of other threads (on Stackoverflow and other sites), all of which have the solution

```cs
((IPEndPoint)(this.client.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address.ToString();
```

however the client is not aware of the public IP address, and as expected, this returns the binded IP address which is 127.0.0.1.

How would I go about getting the public IP? I know it is sent to the server because the server needs to keep track of the client using it however I am unsure how to retrieve it.

Comment: If you connect to 127.0.0.1 with your client, then that will be the address returned by that property. Only if you connect over a network, either LAN or WAN, you'll get a different address.

Comment: I think your misconception is in the word *public*. TCPListener has no concept of public vs internal IP address - only *local* (server) and *remote* (client) addresses. So, if you're expecting to see your public IP issued by your ISP provider while debugging locally - that's not possible.

Comment: I have connected using ngrok and the other computer was over WAN, it is probably because of how ngrok works and I will try this on a server where I don't have to use a tunnel.

Comment: What the meaning of "Public IP" in your question? Public to what? For obtain your Public IPv4, use HttpClient + remote service like this https://www.myip.com/api-docs/

Comment: "Public IP" in this context implies the IP that connects to the TcpListener.

Comment: Usually we use "Remote IP" for this case. Your code is correct. The code will present IP address of connected client. First look into https://ngrok.com/ make answer to the question. ngrok is your client (run on your localhost), therefore you receive 127.0.0.1. The problem is - only ngrok knows real remote IP

Comment: Yes, this was caused by ngrok and it works fine if I listen without tunneling the traffic.
I should have come to this conclusion myself and I apologize for asking this question.